# context menu on click over kinetic rectangle

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, right-click

[image: sample image]

I would like to have a menu on right click over a rectangle. 
you can use this example for a rectangle http://jsfiddle.net/xPbgf/

```
 var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 239,
        y: 75,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'green',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
      });

      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(rect);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);

      rect.on('click',stgClicked);
```

Comment: @Mark: could you please help me out in this.

Comment: kindly see the below link i have done 75%. further i would like to have access to each rectangle separately.http://jsfiddle.net/ajayholla/nusbz3t6/2/